# Code not stopping repeats

Tags: java, printing

I have a LinkedList (I have to use LinkedList for the program) of words that I have read from a file. I read the words from the file and put them in a LinkedList. Then I go through the LinkedList to count the number of times that each word appears, but I only want each word to print once with the number of times it is in the LinkedList.

```
for(int i2 = 0; i2 < b.size(); i2++)
    {
        word2 = b.get(i2);
        for(int j2 = 0; j2 < b.size(); j2++)
        {
            if(word2.equals(b.get(j2)))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        for(int k2 = 0; k2 < wordList.size(); k2++)
        {
            if(word2.equals(k2))
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(found == false)
        {
            wordAndCount = word2 + " " + counter;
            wordList.push(wordAndCount);
        }

        counter = 0;
        found = false;
    }
```

This code is supposed to check if the word is in the second LinkedList (since I don't want to change my original LinkedList) before it puts it in so that when I print the second LinkedList each word only prints once. However it still prints every word every time (exceot for some reason it doesn't print the last word repeatedly). How can I stop this?

I am okay with completely changing the code as long as it makes it print only once!

Answer (score 0):

you compare the word with an index.. that's why it doesn't work..
try this:

```
for (int i2=0;i2<b.size();i2++)
{
    word2 = b.get(i2);
    for (int j2 = 0; j2 < b.size(); j2++)
    {
        if (word2.equals(b.get(j2)))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    for (int k2 = 0; k2 < wordList.size(); k2++)
    {
        if(word2.equals(wordList.get(k2).split(" ")[0])) // <-- here..
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (found == false)
    {
        wordAndCount = word2 + " " + counter;
        wordList.push(wordAndCount);
    }

    counter = 0;
    found = false;
}
```

but this might be better: it will check the existence of the word in `wordlist` first, if it exists, skip further process (counting etc..), and check the next word..

```
OUTER:
for (int i2=0;i2<b.size();i2++)
{
    word2 = b.get(i2);
    for (int k2 = 0; k2 < wordList.size(); k2++)
    {
        if(word2.equals(wordList.get(k2).split(" ")[0])) // <-- here..
        {
            continue OUTER;
        }
    }

    for (int j2 = 0; j2 < b.size(); j2++)
    {
        if (word2.equals(b.get(j2)))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    wordAndCount = word2 + " " + counter;
    wordList.push(wordAndCount);

    counter = 0;
}
```

additional suggestion: you might wanna look at this [HashMap examples](http://www.stanford.edu/group/coursework/docsTech/jgl/api/com.objectspace.jgl.examples.HashMapExamples.html) for even better implementation (using `key` and `value` concept)..